# Difference between #If...then...#else and if...then..else in VBA

Tags: vb.net

I have read the documentation that Microsoft has, but I'm not sure I understood.

Could you Explain the difference/similitude between these two operators? and if possible provide some example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you referring #if directive vs regular if statement? If so, you can read the differences [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx6yas69.aspx#Anchor_2)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a specific programming problem.

Comment: vba IsNot VB.NET  It tells you so on the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if...then...else is executed at run time. You use that in your code to run different statements based on some conditions that can change during the execution of your code.
For example, in a banking software you use the if..then..else statements when a customer is withdrawing money from his/her account. You will use these statements to check if the customer's balance is enough for the transaction.

The #if...#else is for the compiler. For example, you are writing code to send an email to the user. In debug mode (the developer's test), you want to send the email to a hard coded address, but in release mode (production) you want to send the email to actual emails addresses. You can use the DEBUG compiler directive to see if the code is being built in debug mode or not, and depending on that; compiler will compile different statements.